# Does Moq ignore namespaces when setting up mocks?

Tags: unit-testing, moq, mocking

The second assertion never executes in the unit test below:

```
namespace Foo {
    public class MyClass {
    }
}

namespace Bar {
    public class MyClass {
    }
}

namespace Quux {
    public interface IRepo {
        object Get<T>() where T : new();
    }
}

namespace Tests {
    [TestFixture]
    public class MyTests {
        private Mock<Quux.IRepo> repo = new Mock<Quux.IRepo>();

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup() {
            repo.Setup(r => r.Get<Foo.MyClass>()).Returns(new Object());
            repo.Setup(r => r.Get<Bar.MyClass>()).Returns(new Object());
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test() {
            Assert.IsNotNull(repo.Object.Get<Foo.MyClass>());
            Assert.IsNotNull(repo.Object.Get<Bar.MyClass>()); // Never reached.
        }
    }
}
```

Looks like setting up Get<Bar.MyClass>() overwrites the setup for Get<Foo.MyClass>(). Does this mean Moq ignores the namespaces Foo and Bar when setting up Get<T>()? Is there a way around this without renaming the MyClass classes and without implementing IRepo? I'm using Moq 3.1.416.3.

**Update**: Looks like this is [fixed](http://code.google.com/p/moq/issues/detail?id=187) for next release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moq does not ignore namespaces.
This looks like a bug. 
The right place to report it would be at http://code.google.com/p/moq/issues/entry

Comment: Thanks. I'll report it when I have a chance.